# flutter Image.asset dont show,type 'SynchronousFuture<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<AssetManifest>'

Tags: flutter

test.dart

```dart
Container(
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  child: Image.asset("assets/images/danger.jpg",fit: BoxFit.cover,width: 50,height: 50,),
)
```

pubspec.yaml

```yaml
  ...
  assets:
    - assets/images/
  ...
```

======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown while resolving an image:
type 'SynchronousFuture' is not a subtype of type 'Future'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

Comment: I believe there would error coming from elsewhere. Please provide more code.